# Swift 3: Get context of a child viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have `ChildViewController` which inherits from a `ParentViewController` like this: `class ChildViewController: ParentViewController`. In the `ParentViewController` i'm trying to perform the following snippet:

```
let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "anotherViewController") 
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I'm assuming it's not working as it's the `ParentViewController` and the **child** is visible on the actual screen. Is it possible to get he context (self) of the `ChildViewController` in order for the snippet to work?

Thank you for all the help.

Comment: Please elaborate, edit your question. What is the correlation between anotherViewController and ChildViewController/ParentViewController. "I'm assuming it's not working..." what?! What is your current result? What is your desired result? "Is it possible to get he context (self)" get it where? "self" is just a current instance...

Comment: @MaticOblak I'm trying to present a new view controller from the ParentViewController however the app crashes when i try. The ParentViewController is what the ChildViewController is inheriting, AnotherViewController is just another view controller im trying to display.

Comment: What is the crash then? One view controller inheriting from another will not produce a crash, even is a parent is presenting a child, the other way around, parent presenting parent or child presenting child. You may stack/create any number of instances of the same view controller and use them anyway you want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem now (and there is a big IF there) you failed to understand inheritance and your "context".

If you have 2 classes as you say `ParentViewController` and `ChildViewController` where `ChildViewController` is a subclass of `ParentViewController`. You have a method in `ParentViewController` which you assume has no access/context of a `ChildViewController` although the instance itself is a `ChildViewController`... Your assumption here is wrong!

Your `ChildViewController` will INHERIT all of the methods from its superclass `ParentViewController` and all of these methods will have a self reference to `ChildViewController` and not to `ParentViewController`. This means if you have a method `A` and method `B` then override method `B` in child view controller. When parent view controller calls method `B` in method `A` the overridden method will be called. This means although the method `A` is called in parent view controller the method `B` will be called on a child view controller. So there is never a problem of getting a context of a "child". The problem may be that you may not get a context of self as a parent. But this is created as such by design, it is exactly as it should be.

So I guess to answer your question; Yes, it is possible and is actually already happening for you. If you put a breakpoint in the method in your parent view controller and print self (in console type "po self") you should see that the type is actually child view controller.

The issue you are facing is most likely a result of something else. Please add exception breakpoint to see where the crash occurs and see the logs in console to see what it says.